# How to dynamically create Ext.Net store to bind ComboBox?

Tags: asp.net, ext.net

I am using [Ext.Net](http://www.ext.net) 1.3 with ASP.NET 4.0 application.

I have few Ext ComboBox controls which are filled using AJAX query. As the items are dynamically filled, I want to know how to create a dynamic store with which to bind the ComboBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new Store object and add to the Page Controls Collection. The following sample demonstrates a simple scenario.

**Example**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Ext.Net" Namespace="Ext.Net" TagPrefix="ext" %>

<script runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!X.IsAjaxRequest)
        {
            // Create a new Store object
            var store = new Store { 
                // Configure your Properties
            };

            // Add Store to the Page. 
            this.Form.Controls.Add(store);
        }
    }
</script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>Ext.NET Examples</title>
</head>
<body>
<form runat="server">
    <ext:ResourceManager runat="server" />

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I could see that this store will be created at run-time. I want to know how to populate this store at run-time as well.

Comment: There are dozens of GridPanel + Store samples in the Ext.NET Examples Explorer (http://examples.ext.net/). They all demonstrate how to populate a Store. I'd suggest working through a few of those samples.